# Unpack a list of Maps into another Map

Tags: scala

I have a list of maps

```
val names = List(Map("rawname"->"a", "stdname" -> "A"), Map("rawname"->"b", "stdname" -> "B"), Map("rawname"->"c", "stdname" -> "C"))
```

which I want to unpack into

```
val rawToStd = Map("a" -> "A", "b" -> "B", "c" -> "C")
```

I have tried

```
val rawToStd = names.map(e => e.getOrElse("rawname", "") -> e.getOrElse("stdname", "")).toMap
```

which does what I want, but I'm sure there has to be a better (more idiomatic or concise) way. For instance, I dont like the repetition of `getOrElse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect` to achieve this

```
names collect 
      { case element => element("rawname") -> element("stdname")}
toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A, b -> B, c -> C)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that there exist mappings from the `rawname` and `stdname` keys in those `Map`s, you can consider using [`Map.apply`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#apply(key:K):V) instead of `Map.get` and `Map.getOrElse`:

```
scala> val rawToStd = names.map(e => e("rawname") -> e("stdname")).toMap
rawToStd: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A, b -> B, c -> C)
```